# Parameter Missing Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I tried the create action, I **ActionController::ParameterMissing in WelcomeController#create
    param not found: post** for welcome controller. Why would this be happening?

Here is the controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController


  def index1 


 @data = params[:text1]

 @data1 = params[:text2]

end

 def new

    end

 def create

    render text: params[:post].inspect

    @post = Welcome.new(post_params)

    @post.save

    redirect_to @post

end     

private

  def post_params

   params.require(:post).permit(:text1,:text2)

  end

def show

  @post = Welcome.find(params[:id])

end
```

welcome/index.html.erb

```
enter code here

<%= form_tag('/welcome',method: :post,action: :show) do %>

 <p>

<%= label_tag(:text1, "Enter Username :") %>

<%= text_field_tag(:text1, nil, placeholder: 'Enter UserName') %>


</p>

 <p>


 <%= label_tag(:text2, "Enter Password :") %>


 <%= text_field_tag(:text2, nil, placeholder: 'Enter Password') %>


 </p>

 <p>

  <%= submit_tag("Submit")%>

  </p>

  <% end %>
```

Comment: Hi please edit your post to format the code properly, use ctrl+k

Comment: Are you using form_for, or form_tag in your view? Can you please post your form code?

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in WelcomeController#create param not found: post
```

This means that you are not passing a post object into the method post_params, as it requires the post object.

```
params.*require(:post)*.permit(:text1,:text2)
```

Please check your forms on the view page.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in you create action with the line `render text: params[:post].inspect` . Try using this instead:

`render text: post_params.inspect`

Hope this helps!